# Does this simulate the specified time-series?

Tags: r, time-series

This is mostly a question of whether I am coding this correctly. I need to create the following time series in order to answer questions about it: Simulate  an  AR(2)  process  with μ=  2,φ1=  1.2,  and φ2=−0.6  having  error  terms  that  are normally distributed white noise with mean 0 and variance 9.  In order to generate this process, use the random number generation seed 2172 and a sample size of n= 200.

The homework questions ask me things about this process and are easy, but I want to make sure my code is actually simulating what it's supposed to before I move forward.

Here's what I did:

```
set.seed(2172) 
arima.sim(n=200, list(ar=c(1.2, -.6)), innov = rnorm(200, 0, 3)) + 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking a good question and I found few good answer. In the R documentation of the function it is not explicit. But I give you my result which are based on this answer of Rolf Turner. It convinced me :

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/AR-1-with-an-error-term-arima-sim-parameter-question-td4700642.html

The solution is :

```
error.model = function(n){rnorm(n, sd=3)}
x = arima.sim(model = list(ar=c(1.2, -0.6)), n = 200, rand.gen = error.model) + 2
```

To check the order, you can use `pacf`, the question is how to correctly chek the noise because you have an AR. Maybe you can check it with a small sample, for instance t = 1, 2, 3, 4, and check your result.

Good luck.